# Adding some hadoop configuration to a spark application at runtime (through spark-submit)?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I want to send a key-value pair to my spark application something like the following:

```
mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive=true
```

I understand I can do this from the code in the following way:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive","true")
```

But I want to be able to send this property through spark-submit at runtime. Would this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely!

spark-submit (as well as spark-shell) support the `--conf PROP=VALUE` and `--properties-file FILE` options, which allow you specify such arbitrary configurations options. You can then get the values you pass by using the SparkConf `.get` function:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
```

val mrRecursive =

```
conf.get("spark.mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive", mrRecursive)
```

`Spark-submit/spark-shell --help`:

```
  --conf PROP=VALUE           Arbitrary Spark configuration property.
  --properties-file FILE      Path to a file from which to load extra properties. If not
                              specified, this will look for conf/spark-defaults.conf.
```

Spark docs regarding [dynamically] loading properties: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: Well, not exactly what I want. My code is already in production, and I want to skip the build-test-deploy cycle. I want to directly pass hadoop properties to the spark application without having to add the two extra lines of code(`conf.get` and `sc.hadoopConfiguration.set`).

Comment: @AnkitKhettry There does not appear to currently be a way to pass hadoop configuration options directly through spark-submit without having some application code to apply it. If you were running a hadoop jar, it would be easy to pass it. The last ditch effort I had to try to make it work was passing `--driver-java-options "-Dmapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive"` but that too was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

Without code modification, such approach can be used.

Hadoop Configuration reads file "core-default.xml" during creation, description is here:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html

If put values in "core-default.xml", and include directory with file in classpath with spark-submit "driver-class-path" parameter, it can work.